# Type file button

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Hello I ask pretty much a similar question yesterday and I don't know why it behaves like that at least for me

```
<label>Upload songs/images
    <label for="song" class="button small-12 hollow">Upload File</label> 
    <input type="file" id="exampleFileUpload" class="show-for-sr"> 
</label>
```

And when I try attaching a plug-in (jQuery plugin) to that input element I'm asking for help is because I would really like to use it thanks and I have asked everywhere and tried searching online but no luck.

Was trying to use this with button https://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile/

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of what you have done so far? This way people can explain you what is going (wr)on(g).

Comment: I attached a click event to the input element with a alert inside and notice that the click event fires before the input type file can do it's default job can you please paste to me the proper way or other for script tags when using foundation Mike

Comment: Couldn't post a jsfiddle example don't know how to properly use it yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full answer available in response to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43860148/button-not-displaying-menu); in short, the `label` needs to wrap around the file input control, and remove the label's `for` attribute.

Comment: The plug in wraps the input in a div so I solve the issue by adding foundation button classes to that div, so no need to use label. But thanks for the reply

Comment: Your answer works tooo thanks, and is a better approach thanks again