# Button not displaying menu

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

About a week ago i posted a question but couldn't get it answer because i didn't know how to use jsfiddle or codepen but i figured it out.

my problem is that the button doesn't work now if you click around it it will display the file search box this is the sample:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWaYzJ

```
<label> Uploads
  <label for="exampleFileUpload" class="button">Upload File</label>
  <input type="file" id="exampleFileUpload" class="show-for-sr">
</label>
```

now if i detached the plugin from element then button works again.

Answer (score 0):

change your outer `label` to `div` seems to solve your problem like this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YVYYXj)

```
<div> Uploads
<label for="exampleFileUpload" class="button">Upload File</label>
<input type="file" id="exampleFileUpload" class="show-for-sr">
</div>
```

Comment: the reason it works in your  example is because you forgot to include the plugin if you check codepen console it says MultiFile is not a function . Whit the pluging working and instead of label using div the button doenst work either not even clicking outside button.

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="exampleFileUpload" class="button">Upload File</label>
<input type="file" id="exampleFileUpload" class="show-for-sr">
```

And make your javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#exampleFileUpload').onClick({
        MultiFile();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the reference to the MultiFile source file - that's what causes the "MultiFile is not a function" error.  You will need to include the MultiFile directly in the source for the codepen (as you already have).

Second, the label needs to wrap the input, and it cannot use the `for` attribute (since that relies on the `name` attribute for the target, which you have not set):

```
<div> Uploads
  <label class="button">Upload File
    <input type="file" id="exampleFileUpload" class="show-for-sr" multiple>
  </label>
</div>
```